# How to create managed path in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to create managed path in sharepoint 2013, please help me out for this. Instead of **site** i want to create **users** in url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open central admin and follow the steps in below image to create managed path.

[image]